# How can I limit discount coupons amount

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I created a cart price rule 5% whole cart. but I want to limit maximum dicount amount to 30$.

for example if The customer buy with 1500$ still can Apply the discount with maximum discount amount 30$.

How can limit the dicount amount ?

Answer (score 0):

It's out of box requirement.

you can use any 3rd party extension for special promotion.

e.g amasty special promotion for magento 2

https://amasty.com/special-promotions-for-magento-2.html